# One Excel spreadsheet to multiple SQL tables, either Bulk or LINQ will do

Tags: sql, linq, excel, bulk

I'm writting a c#.net app and need help with the following.

I've got 4 tables:

Users (Name, ..., UsrID)

Products (Name, ProdID)

Ratings (Rating, RatID)

ProdRatings (UsrID, ProdID, RatID, DateRated, RatedBy)

Now I've got an excel sheet containg view made of tables above:

Sheet1: UserName, ProductName, Rating, DateRated)

I need to fill up this spreadsheet with users and their products and rating and insert it all to the sql db.

Now I can import into single table no problem, but struggling to import to all 4 at once.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use sql server:

```
insert into users (name)
   SELECT distinct a.UserName
   FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
    'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\test\xltest.xls', [Sheet1$]) a
   where not exists (select null from Users where Name = a.UserName)

insert into Products (Name)
   SELECT distinct a.ProductName
   FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
    'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\test\xltest.xls', [Sheet1$]) a
   where not exists (select null from Products where Name = a.ProductName)

insert into Ratings (Rating)
   SELECT distinct a.Rating
   FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
    'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\test\xltest.xls', [Sheet1$]) a
   where not exists (select null from Ratings where Name = a.Rating)

insert into ProdRatings (UsrID, ProdID, RatID, DateRated)
   SELECT Users.UsrID, Products.ProdID, Ratings.RatID, a.DateRated
   FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
    'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\test\xltest.xls', [Sheet1$]) a
      inner join Users
         on a.UserName = Users.Name
      inner join Products
         on a.ProductName = Products.Name
      inner join Ratings
         on a.Rating = Ratings.Rating
      left join ProdRatings
         on Users.UsrID = ProdRatings.UsrID
         and Products.ProdID = ProdRatings.ProdID
         and Ratings.RatID = ProdRatings.RatID
   where ProdRatings.ID is null
```

First you import new users, products and ratings, then ProdRatings.

If you do not use sql server, first import Excel file in your standard fashion into temporary table and then do partial inserts. I hope this suits your needs.